# cannot create c++ project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I suppose since I installed Visual Studio 2012, I cannot create C++ project in Visual Studio 2010. But, I am not sure new installation of VS 2012 is related to this problem.

The problem I am really struggling is that neither hint message nor notification are shown when I try to create a new C++ project.

I have tried several ways from google even include stackoverflow, but failed.

Is there anyone who knows any solutions or has any workarounds?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to create a project?

Comment: nothing happen apart from just project creation wizard shown again without any message

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you unless you give exact details of when and how this problem started occurring.

Comment: You're right and unfortunately that is a big problem. All I experienced was just it. I cannot offer further detail.

Comment: I got this problem few days/weeks ago. I didn't do anything and now it works... Did you try to reboot ? Moreover, MSVC11 also broke the MSVC10 linker (COFF error or something like that). I solved the second problem installing the MSVC10 SP1. Maybe this can help you, maybe not :)

Comment: Of course I did server time re-install Visual studio 2010 and SP1. Even though I sorted out it, I still do not know what factor affected to the solution. so mysterious~

Answer (score 1):

1) I wouldn't be at all surprised if installing MSVS 2012 is the culprit.  VMs are Good :)

2) You should definitely look at the Windows event log (if you haven't already)

3) You can also run MSVS 2010 with logging as follows:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272%28VS.80%29.aspx

  `Devenv.exe /log "C:\My Files\MyLog.txt"`

Comment: PS: Use "vcsexpress.exe /log" instead of "DevEnv /log" if you happen to have MSVS2010 Express.  And please do consider using VMs.  I've had extremely good luck with both VMWare and VirtualBox.  All you need is a reasonable CPU (64-bit and VT-extensions are both a must), a reasonable amount of RAM (++4-6GB), and a reasonable amount of disk.  I can compile everything from Turbo C++/Win95 through MSVS2012/Windows 8, with J2EE/Websphere in between.  IMHO...

Comment: OMG! It works well after I installed Visual C++ 2010 Express. What does VC++ Express do! It's definitely bizarre..

Comment: Thank you! paulsm4 and other guys.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem in "microsoft visual studio express 2012 for window desktop" and now it's perfectly working after having gone through repair option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another version (or express edition) of visual studio installed on the same PC that is previously used to create console applications, that might be the issue. I had the same issue and I had Visual C++ 2008 on the same computer and I could either use the visual C++ for console applications or uninstall it completely. Hope this helps!